# Smoking marijuana on territory of the Netherlands embassy

Tags: legal, netherlands, factoids, embassies

As far as I know the territory of the country's embassy is considered to be the country's territory. So, is it legal, for example, to smoke weed on the territory of the embassy of the Netherlands (or any other country, where marijuana is legal)? The question is just to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: Just smoke it in Colorado or Washington in the US. The Netherlands is no longer the most progressive country in the world when it comes to drugs.

Answer (score 8):

> As far as I know the territory of the country's embassy is considered to be the country's territory.

That is a common misconception, but still wrong. The diplomatic status of the embassy limits access to the embassy for official representatives of the host country, but it does not change the territorial association of the premises or the validity of the host country's laws.

For example, in the Dutch embassy in London, UK law applies, but UK police is not allowed to enter the premises unless they are allowed to do so by the ambassador.

Comment: It is also a common misconception that marijuana is legal in the Netherlands. Possesion and use is a criminal offence, that is tolerated under certain circumstances. Not causing a nuisance is one of them. So the embassy can, and will, forbid you to do so on their territory.

Comment: It's also guaranteed that the Ministry of Foreign Affairs has rules against any illegal drug use at their facilities.